# How do you determine if an upload completed successfully in S3 presigned URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using S3, I can generate a pre-signed URL to upload a file, but I can't find a way to determine from another resource whether the:

1. upload completed successfully or not.
2. another upload is in progress.

I am asking in the context of Expo's `FileSystem.uploadAsync` which according to the documentation uploads in the background.

Here's the snippet of my upload code.

```
      const startResult = await this.webClient.post("/v3/upload/start", {
        category: meta.category,
        contentType: meta.contentType,
        contentMd5Hash: fileInfo.md5,
        contentLength: fileInfo.size,
      });
      if (startResult.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error(
          `start result got ${startResult.status} expecting 200.  ${startResult.data}`
        );
      }

      const {
        presignedUploadUrl,
        contentMd5,
        completionToken,
      } = startResult.data;

      const result = await FileSystem.uploadAsync(
        presignedUploadUrl,
        fileInfo.uri,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-MD5": contentMd5 as string,
            "Content-Type": meta.contentType,
          },
          httpMethod: "PUT",
        }
      );

      // I need to do this to indicate that the upload was completed
      // All this tells the backend that it is done, but there's no other
      // proof that it was done.
      const completeResult = await this.webClient.post("/v3/upload/complete", {
        completionToken,
        presignedUploadUrl,
      });

      const { artifactId } = completeResult.data;

      console.log(artifactId);
```

Comment: When you say Expo's `FileSystem.uploadAsync` are you using [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemuploadasyncurl-fileuri-options)? It returns a [Promise](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#returns-4). So, have you tried checking the HTTP status and compared if it's returned asap or after the upload is successful?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how that works, but I've not gone as far as implementing it.  I am just testing via postman.

Comment: Could you provide the code implementation for what you have already tried? That can give some info on what could be introduced.